# how to reate a dataframe name using for loop index i as suffix

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I would like to create the name of the `dataframe` using the index name `i` of the for loop.

As in the example below, index `i` is traversed by calling US, JP, DE, UK, and CN, and I would like to create `dataframes` with name in suffix format such like `df_US`, `df_JP`, `df_DE`, `df_UK`, `df_CN`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



for i in ['US','JP','DE','UK','CN']:
    df_{i} = pd.DataFrame()


#   Input In [32]
#     rand_{i} = pd.DataFrame()
#          ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot directly create variable names dynamically in Python like df_US, df_JP, etc. However, you can achieve a similar result using a dictionary to store your dataframes with keys corresponding to the index names.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframes = {}

for i in ['US', 'JP', 'DE', 'UK', 'CN']:
    dataframes[f'df_{i}'] = pd.DataFrame()

# Now you can access your dataframes like this:
df_US = dataframes['df_US']
df_JP = dataframes['df_JP']
df_DE = dataframes['df_DE']
df_UK = dataframes['df_UK']
df_CN = dataframes['df_CN']
```

By using a dictionary, you can create and access your dataframes dynamically based on the index names.